# Dynamic Multilevel menu in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to implement a dynamic multilevel menu on quick launch in sharepoint 2010. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the Modifying the Menu Control section of [How to: Customize the Display of Quick Launch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms466994.aspx).

Inside the master page, you have to change the `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` attribute of the `AspMenu` control with an id of `V4QuickLaunchMenu`:

> The default value of the MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels attribute is 0. This disables flyout menus. Setting the value to 1 means that the first menu level below the last level on the static menu appears in a flyout menu. In this case, flyoutmenus appear for the first level below the headings.

Comment: thank's for your answer, i know your solution but i need custom navigation solution as same sharepoint navigation that support multilevel menu.
the sharepoint navigation in the site setting we have two level (heading and link) and i need more than two level menu.